# apostrophe after the name in the author section

Tags: titles, ieeetran

I tried writing the author names under the author section, this happened right after I changed the usual way of formating this particular section. There seems to be an apostrophe right after the name? Not sure why though. Is there any way to remove it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\title{ Architecture of the century\\
}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{John Doe, \IEEEauthorrefmark,
Rachael Moore,\IEEEauthorrefmark, David S,\IEEEauthorrefmark,\\
Raphael Andrew,\IEEEauthorrefmark,
Jane Dooe,\IEEEauthorrefmark,
Will Jackson,\IEEEauthorrefmark, 
Tibitabo Sandru\IEEEauthorrefmark,
}
\IEEEauthorblockA{SRH Hochschule Heidelberg\\
Heidelberg, Germany\\
Email \IEEEauthorrefmark * \{john.doe, rachael.moore, david.s, raphael.andrew, tibitabo.sandru, will.jackson\}\\
@stud.123-sandiago.com,\\
\IEEEauthorrefmark *\{ Will.jackson,Tibitabo.Sandru\}@sandiago.com
}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of posting a fragment of code, can you please make your code compilable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `\IEEEauthorrefmark` macro incorrectly. It takes a single numeric argument which will automatically generate a matching character for the affiliations or emails. It needs to be immediately after the name and before the comma.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\title{ Architecture of the century
}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{John Doe\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Rachael Moore\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, David S\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},\\
Raphael Andrew\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Jane Dooe\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Will Jackson\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, 
Tibitabo Sandru\IEEEauthorrefmark{2},
}
\IEEEauthorblockA{SRH Hochschule Heidelberg\\
Heidelberg, Germany\\
Email \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}\{john.doe, rachael.moore, david.s, raphael.andrew, tibitabo.sandru, will.jackson\}\\
@stud.123-sandiago.com,\\
\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}\{Will.jackson,Tibitabo.Sandru\}@sandiago.com
}}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: There's still a wrongly placed comma.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. Fixed.